# Update status of array in state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-state

I want to change update the state of an array based on the selected value. So I have 3 elements in the array `boardStatus` in the `state`. Now when the 2nd TouchableOpacity is pressed (`handleBoardPress(2)`), the status of only the 2nd element in the array, `{id:2, status:true}` should be `true` and 1 and 3 should be `false`.

My Code:

```
class TestApp extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
    boardStatus:[
        {id:1, status:false},
        {id:2, status:true},
        {id:3, status:true},
    ]
  };
 }

handleBoardPress=(id)=>{
    var id = id.toString();

    for(i=0, i!=id, i<=3, i++){     // How do I code this part?
        this.setState({
            boardStatus[i]: false
        })
    }   
}

render() {
return (
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={()=>this.handleBoardPress(1)}>
        <Text>One</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={()=>this.handleBoardPress(2)}>
        <Text>Two</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>

    <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={()=>this.handleBoardPress(3)}>
        <Text>Three</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

How do I code the `handleBoardPress` function?

Comment: But what should happen to the state when you click on 1st Touchable opacity, instead of 2nd? If the behavior must be similar to the 2nd one, then the below answers should work, otherwise, they won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this using map.

```js
  handleBoardPress = id => {
    let updatedBoard = this.state.boardStatus.map(el => ({...el, status: el.id === id}));
    this.setState({ boardStatus: updatedBoard});
  };
```

Comment: How do I setState to mark all the elements in the `boardStatus` as true?  Lets say I want to call a function called `resetStatus`. What logic would I use to update the status of all elements in `boardStatus` as true?

Comment: @Somename it would be like this ` this.setState({ boardStatus: this.state.boardStatus.map(el => ({...el, status: true}))})`

Comment: @Somename [here](https://snack.expo.io/@suleymansah/51a7e6) is sample with select all and deselect all.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
handleBoardPress = (id) => {
    var id = id.toString();
    var boardStatus = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        if (i == id) {
            boardStatus.push({id: i, status: true});
        } else {
            boardStatus.push({id: i, status: false});
        }
    }

    this.setState({boardStatus});
}
```

Comment: Although the solution 'works', using external iterator can cause unwanted change in state in case the number of elements in `boardStatus` change. I'd rather suggest using `map` over `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah, map is better, but it also won't work if an invalid id is passed in. For example, if he adds another TouchableOpacity without updating the state.

Comment: @SachinGadagi you are right, I used map, it is way simpler and cleaner.

Comment: My point being, it would be a lot simpler to just use an object where the keys are the id instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate - change the state like this - `this.state = {activeBoard:null}` and the `handleBoardPress` would be like this -

```
handleBoardPress(boardId){
   this.setState({activeBoard:boardId})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a more ES6 approach

```
handleBoardPress = id => {
  const { boardStatus } = this.state
  const oldStatuses = boardStatus.filter(item => item.id !== id)

  this.setState({
    boardStatus: [
      ...oldStatuses, {id, status: true}
    ]
  })
}
```

It avoid the old classic for loop which is no longer really used today in Javascript code.